# vb.net DataGridview compare

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagridview

I am having 2 DataGridView in my vb.net form. datagridview1 has a DataSource with sql server DB.

**Expected behavior**
If I double click my datagridview1 my selected value should be displayed in datagridview2 and that value should be removed in datagridview1. This should repeat whenever I double click my datagridview1 hence my datagridview2 value should not be in  datagridview1 `enter code here`

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count - 1
            iRowIndex = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(i).RowIndex
            icolindex = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(i).ColumnIndex
            cell_value = DataGridView1.Rows(iRowIndex).Cells(icolindex).Value
            selected_row_pk = DataGridView1.Rows(iRowIndex).Cells(0).Value
        Next
        If (DataGridView2.RowCount = 0 & DataGridView2.ColumnCount = 0) Then
            Dim dt1 As New DataTable
            DataGridView2.Rows.Add(selected_row_pk, cell_value)
            frst_rem_CELL_value = cell_value
            frst_rem_ROW_PK_value = selected_row_pk
            dt1 = DataGridView1.DataSource
            dt1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Delete()
            dt1.AcceptChanges()
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt1
            dtt = DataGridView1.DataSource
            a = 2
        Else

            If a = 2 Then
                dtt.Rows.Add(frst_rem_ROW_PK_value, frst_rem_CELL_value)
                dtt.AcceptChanges()
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dtt
                dtt5.Columns.Add("id", GetType(Integer))
                dtt5.Columns.Add("expence_date", GetType(String))
                dt_for_grid2.Columns.Add("id", GetType(Integer))
                dt_for_grid2.Columns.Add("expence_date", GetType(String))
                a = 1
            End If

            If CLng(counter) Mod 2 > 0 Then
                frst_rem_CELL_value1 = cell_value
                frst_rem_ROW_PK_value1 = selected_row_pk
                dt_for_grid2.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Delete()
                dt_for_grid2.AcceptChanges()
                dt_for_grid2.Rows.Add(frst_rem_ROW_PK_value2, frst_rem_CELL_value2)
                dt_for_grid2.AcceptChanges()
                DataGridView2.Rows.Add(selected_row_pk, cell_value)
                Dim rowIndex As Integer = DataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex
                DataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex)
                Dim distinctDT As DataTable = dt_for_grid2.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "id", "expence_date")
                distinctDT.AcceptChanges()
                DataGridView1.DataSource = distinctDT
            Else

                frst_rem_CELL_value2 = cell_value
                frst_rem_ROW_PK_value2 = selected_row_pk
                Dim rowIndex As Integer = DataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex
                dt_for_grid1 = DataGridView1.DataSource
                dt_for_grid1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Delete()
                dt_for_grid1.AcceptChanges()
                dt_for_grid2 = dt_for_grid1
                dtt5.Rows.Add(selected_row_pk, cell_value)
                dtt5.AcceptChanges()
                dt_for_grid1.AcceptChanges()
                DataGridView4.DataSource = dtt5
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dt_for_grid2
                DataGridView2.Rows.Add(selected_row_pk, cell_value)
                DataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex)
            End If
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
        DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(0), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you just trying to move an item from one list to the other when double-clicked?  Meaning, double-click to complete an item and remove it from the incomplete list to the complete list, or something along those lines?

Comment: Yes actually consider 2 buckets bucket 1 contains 3 ball which is 1.red ball 2.blue ball 3.green ball if i pick red ball which should be moved to bucket2  then bucket1 shound contain only blue and green ball if i pick green ball from bucket1. Bucket2 already contains red ball right, that shoud be moved to bucket1 and newly pickup green ball moves to bucket2  
Hene bucket2 should aleayd maintain only one ball, this is what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

When you double click a cell, do you want to move whole row from DGV1 to DGV2?

Should data from DGV1 go to specific row in DGV2?

```
Private Sub DGV1_CellContentDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV1.CellContentDoubleClick
    DGV2.Rows.Add(DGV1(0,e.RowIndex).Value,DGV1(1,e.RowIndex).Value) 'adds data from selected DGV1 row to DGV2
    DGV1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex) 'I guess this is different with databound datagridview.
End Sub
```

If DGV2 is not created at runtime, you can add columns when form is loaded.

Comment: i have to move only selected row

Comment: Location doesn't matter to you (can we use rows.add)?

Comment: if i click dgv1 data removed and added two dgv2, if another time when i click means now  dgv2 data should be moved to dgv1, and dgv1 secondly selected data move to dgv2 hence dgv2 should carry only one data.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you have tried to explain, can you paraphrase.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would approach it differently, if I understand it correctly.  The data table should have an additional "group" field.  When you click on the row in datagridview1, update the "group" field in the table from "1" to "2".  The data source for the first grid would only show table data for group "1", and the data source for the second grid would only show table data for group "2"  The click would do the update, the grids should refresh, and you should get the results you want.